# Does Madrid's metro offer children's fares?

Tags: trains, fares, madrid

I read the [Madrid Metro website](http://www.metromadrid.es) and none of the fare tables I can find seem to mention age.  Most other major metro / underground systems that I've seen charge less for children and/or seniors.

Does Madrid not do this?  Why not?

Comment: My experience in North America is that kids fares are the exception, not the rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About the only difference is noted at the [bottom of the page of ticket prices](http://www.metromadrid.es/en/viaja_en_metro/tarifas/billetes/):

> Children under the age of 4 may travel without a ticket.

So yes, some children get a discount, but not all.

However, there is a [tourist season travel ticket](http://www.metromadrid.es/en/viaja_en_metro/tarifas/abonos/contenido02.html), for x number of days which you can purchase, for certain zones and various combos.  For this, children under 11 get a 50% discount, as indicated on the page.

Comment: As a note to future readers, since recently, children up to 6 years can travel for free: http://www.metromadrid.es/en/comunicacion/prensa/2015/January/noticia03.html

From 4 to 6 it does require a special card, though, so it's not really suitable for tourists.

Answer (score 3):

Children under the age of 4 [don't need a ticket](http://www.metromadrid.es/en/viaja_en_metro/tarifas/billetes/index.html).

There are [monthly/season tickets](http://www.metromadrid.es/en/viaja_en_metro/tarifas/abonos/index.html) at reduced rates for people under 23 as well as 65 and over. And a [special ticket](http://www.metromadrid.es/en/viaja_en_metro/tarifas/abonos/contenido03.html) for "official large families" and hadicapped persons.

However, there don't seem to be any reduced rates for regular single tickets.